# boolean conditions in if statement

Tags: php, conditional-statements

I want to double check something about multiple conditions in a boolean if statement in PHP.  Given that I write:

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !isset($_POST['report_btn'])) {...}
```

can this be re-written as

```
if(! ( empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['report_btn']) ) ) {...}
```

I'm wanting to remove one of the exclamation marks to see if I can make the code a bit tidier.  The logic is to see if I can execute the code if POST data has been sent to a page but the `'report_btn'` value is not set.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123: using `empty` instead of `isset` will behave differently.

Comment: I always thought that the `$_POST` variable is always sent with a header request, so is therefore always set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, You can not write the above condition as below condition:

**Reason:**

for:

```
if(! ( empty($_POST) && isset($_POST['report_btn']) ) ) {...}
```

the result matrix will:

```
first_statement second_statement result
   true            true          false
   true            false         true
   false           true          true
   false           false         true
```

And for the below

```
if(!empty($_POST) && !isset($_POST['report_btn'])) {...}
```

The result matrix will be:

```
first_statement second_statement result
   true            true          false
   true            false         false
   false           true          false
   false           false         true
```

It means both code are not similar.

Comment: They are not, but `!empty($_POST) && !isset($_POST['report_btn'])` yields the same result as `!(empty($_POST) || isset($_POST['report_btn']))`

Answer (score 2):

Boolean logic says that

```
!A && !B == !(A || B)
!A || !B == !(A && B)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to know how to transform your logical expression properly.

It's good to read about [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) which includes your case.

> "not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
>
> "not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)".